# XML Attribute for specifying pivotXType and pivotYType in ScaleAnimation

Tags: android, android-layout

this may sound silly, but i can´t find anywhere how to specify the pivotXType and pivotYType of a ScaleTAnimation.

I know how to do it programatically, but i need to specify it via XML (i need it for transition between activities, using overridePendingTransition method)

Here´s the code that works:

```
 Animation animation=new ScaleAnimation(1,0,1,0,ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,(float)0.5,ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,(float)0.5);  
  animation.setDuration(1000);
```

Here´s the XML, without the XML attribute i´m looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:toYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="0.5"        
    android:pivotY="0.5"
    android:duration="2000"
    />
```

I checked out the documentation at http://developers.androidcn.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html, but didn´t find any answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hope no one even bothered reading my question.
I was making a mistake when writing the xml, here´s the correct code for the effect i wanted (scaling the new activity from 100% size to 0% size, right in the middle of the screen).
Correct values for pivotX and pivotY are 50% instead of 0.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:toYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"        
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="600"
    />
```

Comment: Please accept this as your answer so the question will effectively be closed (people will more likely skip an accepted answer). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! as much as I know this is undocumented.

Answer (score 21):

I know the answer has been already posted, but I thought I would write a few words of explanation.
Pivots in xml can be set to three types of values (example using value `50`):

- `50%` - percentages; Corresponding to the type of pivoting [`Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#RELATIVE_TO_SELF). `50%` basically means that it will pivot in the middle of the view.
- `50%p` - parent percentages; Corresponding to the type of pivoting [`Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#RELATIVE_TO_PARENT). `50%p` means that it will pivot in the middle of the parent view.
- `50` - absolute; Corresponding to the type of pivoting [`Animation.ABSOLUTE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#ABSOLUTE). `50` means pivoting at the `50` pixels from the top/left (depends on the type of pivot - y/x)

Comment: Thanks great answer - this is very useful when you view is already translated and you want to scale animate around a new center (shrink grow animation for example) - you than have to calculate your absolute center of the translated view and animate around this new center.